# How to send a mail in activiti?

Tags: email, process, task, diagram, activiti

I made a process using activiti-explorer and I deployed.I have a startevent,mail task,user task and endevent.When I started the process it says "Warning!Could not send e mail". What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Activiti engine sends e-mails trough an external mail server with SMTP capabilities. To actually send e-mails, the engine needs to know how to reach the mail server. Following properties can be set in the activiti.cfg.xml configuration file.

More info: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnEmailTask